# Decreasing computational time on moving kernel in R

Tags: r

Say you have a matrix **M** containing prime numbers.

```
# For the sake of simplicity
# I will not use primes for the example 

M <- matrix(runif(100,0,1), ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
```

My goal is to compute the prime product of smaller kernel (say 3 by 3) at every position of matrix **M** excluding edges. Currently, I have the following:

```
prime_barcode <- function(prime.matrix){
    # Starting positions
    # not using edges as kernel center
    x_idx <- c(2,ncol(prime.matrix)-1)
    y_idx <- c(2,nrow(prime.matrix)-1)

    # Creating 0 vector for replacement 
    prime_barcode <- rep(0,(ncol(prime.matrix)-2)*(nrow(prime.matrix)-2))
    prime_loc <- 1

    # Looping over every column and row - excluding edges
    for(i in seq(x_idx[1],x_idx[2])){
        for(j in seq(y_idx[1],y_idx[2])){
            tmp <- as.vector(prime.matrix[i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1])
            prime_barcode[prime_loc] <- prod(tmp)
            prime_loc <- prime_loc +1
        }
    }
    return(prime_barcode)
}
```

This seems to be quite slow in R for large matrices.

Is there a way to decrease the computational time or are there R functions that can accomplish this and that I have missed?

Comment: O(N^2) algorithm......

Comment: Not being a computer scientist, I am not sure I follow your comment. Are you saying the code provided above cannot be improved ?

Comment: I believe you want `prime.matrix[(i-1):(i+1), (j-1):(j+1)]` in your function. "(j-1):(j+1)" is not the same as "j-1:j+1".  Fixing this logic error will improve performance.  For a bigger boost look at Rcpp package and convert from interpreted R to compiled C

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was trying to avoid using Rcpp because I have no C experience at all. Now is the time to learn I guess